How to make pylance recongize type stubs
I have written a python library with strict typing.
It uses a devcontainer, and is setup with pre-commit conditions including mypy.
Everything works fine, and I've used this workflow on many projects.
But if i try to activate typing with pylance can not recognize the pyi files in the same folder with the same name

#test.pyi
def myfunc(arg1: str, arg2: str) -> str: ...

#test.py
def myfunc(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2



Ive never had the combination of .pyi files and pylance strict type checking before, using one but not the other works, but having them together don't. I do not understand why.
Tried using pyrightconfig, stubs folder, typing folder etc. Nothing leads anywhere :( Tried checking around on forums, here, but seems like no one else have had this issue? Does anyone have any usable example guides on how to use typestubs with pylance typechecking?

I would be surprised if what you were trying to do "worked". .pyis determine how other modules interface with the module you're type-checking. It's ambiguous what .pyis are supposed to do when you're editing the implementation file corresponding to the .pyi - should the implementation file definition take precedence, or should the .pyi definitions take precedence?

@dROOOze is correct - stub files are for the outer world, not for the corresponding impl file. Note that there's no ambiguity here: stub files were designed to take precedence and I'm not aware of any changes to that. If you have def foo() -> None: ... stub and def foo(x): ... impl, then foo(x) signature won't be visible to external users. It doesn't matter within the file - stubs aren't merged back into it, so whole file is checked as if it had def foo(x: Any) -> Any defined.

my guess is that you're not using a module, so just running test.py, it wouldn't know really what typing to look up.  I suspect if you put the code in question into a module (e.g a subdir with an __init__.py then it will work.

@STerliakov "It doesn't matter within the file - stubs aren't merged back into it" - is this in the typing specifications somewhere? I ask because at least one linter which interfaces with mypy that I've used doesn't behave this way, and behaved as though it merged the definition from the .pyi back to the source - although that might be due to the linter's use of mypy's --shadow-file option..

@dROOOze apparently the spec doesn't consider such case explicitly, because stub files are intended for external consumers and assume that the original library isn't typechecked at all. Precedence of .pyi over .py is documented here, and there's also no mention of merging stub and impl files - I think it's a reasonable assumption to make that running mypy file.py should not take file.pyi into account, since there's no import file and stub files declare importable symbols.
